# error when trying to return an integer as the entity

Tags: java, jersey

I noticed that when I used `Response.status(201).entity(id).build`, it returns the following error :

**Severe: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.lang.Integer, genericType=class java.lang.Integer.**

```
    @POST
    @Produces({"application/json"})
    public Response createUser(
            @NotNull @FormParam("username") String username,
            @NotNull @FormParam("password") String password,
            @NotNull @FormParam("role") String role) {

        int id = 12;
        return Response.status(201).entity(id).build();

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single `Integer` object can't be converted to JSON, because JSON it's like map (key-value pairs). You have to options:

1) Change returned type to text

```
@Produces({"text/plain"})
```

2) Create a class which represents your single value as JSON, like:

```
class IntValue {
    private Integer value;

    public IntValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    // getter, setter
}
```

and then do following

```
return Response.status(201).entity(new IntValue(id)).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

`"1"` is not valid `JSON`. You should wrap you number to some entity or change `"application/json"` to `"application/text"`.